# Able to use UIKit class in a background thread

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, uikit

I experimented and was able to instantiate `UIKit` class (`UIImageView` in this case) in a background thread without issue.  I have seen app crashes by doing things with `UIKit` on a background thread.  Behind the scene, what causes exception when dealing with `UIKit` on a non-main thread? For example, if I stay completely away from dealing with the view hierarchy, is it safe?

Answer (score 4):

It is not safe. There are some documented tasks that are safe to call on a background task, e.g. drawing a string into an image, accesing `UIFont`, pushing/popping/using current graphics context. However, mostly the behavior is **undefined** or documented as unsafe. You never know what shared resources the classes are using in the background (or they will in future releases). They could use shared memory pools, for example.

From my experience, in most cases you won't see a problem if the `UIView` is not added to any `UIWindow` but still it is not safe.

For example, I think that loading things from nibs (using `UINib`) must be done only from the main thread... and any view can load subviews from nibs.